# How to access columns that contains the argument in data frame and sort in decreasing order

Tags: r

I am dealing with a data frame with column names, company name, division name all_production_2017, bad_production_2017...with many years back

Now I am writing a function that takes a company *name* and a *year* as arguments and summarize the company's production in that year. Then sort it by decreasing order in all_production_*year*

I have already converted the year to a string and filter the rows and columns required. But how can I sort it by a specific column? I do not know how to access that column name because the argument year is the suffix of that.

Here is a rough sketch of the structure of my data frame.

structure(list(company = c("DLT", "DLT", "DLT", "MSF", "MSF", "MSF"),
               division = c("Marketing", "CHANG1", "CAHNG2", "MARKETING", "CHANG1M", "CHANG2M"),
               all_production_2000 = c(15, 25, 25, 10, 25, 18),
               good_production_2000 = c(10, 24, 10, 8, 10, 10),
               bad_production_2000 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5)))

with data from 2000 to 2017
I want to write a function that given a name of the company and a year.
It can filter out the company and the year relevant, and sort the all_production_thatyear, by decreasing order.

I have done so far.

```
ExportCompanyYear <- function(company.name, year){
   year.string <- toString(year)
   x <- filter(company.data, company == company.name) %>%
      select(company, division, contains(year.string))
}
```

I just do not know how to sort by decreasing order because i do not know how to access the column name which contains the argument year.

Comment: Please share the structure of your data.frame and the function code you have written so far. To share your data.frame structure copy paste the output of `dput(head(df,10))` in the question description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to reshape your data in such a way that `year` values could be passed as a parameter.

To create a reproducible example, I have added another year `2001` in the data.

```
df = data.frame(company = c("DLT", "DLT", "DLT", "MSF", "MSF", "MSF"), division = c("Marketing", "CHANG1", "CAHNG2", "MARKETING", "CHANG1M", "CHANG2M"), all_production_2000 = c(15, 25, 25, 10, 25, 18), good_production_2000 = c(10, 24, 10, 8, 10, 10), bad_production_2000 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5),all_production_2001 = 2*c(15, 25, 25, 10, 25, 18), good_production_2001 = 2*c(10, 24, 10, 8, 10, 10), bad_production_2001 = 2*c(2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5))
```

Now you can reshape the data using the `reshape` function in R.
Here, the variables **"all_production","good_production","bad_production"** are varying with time, and year values are changing for those variables.

So we specify `v.names = c("all_production","good_production","bad_production")`.

```
df2 = reshape(df,direction="long",
v.names = c("all_production","good_production","bad_production"),
varying = names(df)[3:8],
idvar = c("company","division"),
timevar = "year",times = c(2000,2001))
```

For your data.frame you can specify `times=2000:2017` and `varying=3:ncol(df)`

```
>df2
                   company  division year all_production good_production bad_production
DLT.Marketing.2000     DLT Marketing 2000             15               2             10
DLT.CHANG1.2000        DLT    CHANG1 2000             25               1             24
DLT.CAHNG2.2000        DLT    CAHNG2 2000             25               2             10
MSF.MARKETING.2000     MSF MARKETING 2000             10               1              8
MSF.CHANG1M.2000       MSF   CHANG1M 2000             25               3             10
MSF.CHANG2M.2000       MSF   CHANG2M 2000             18               5             10
DLT.Marketing.2001     DLT Marketing 2001             30               4             20
DLT.CHANG1.2001        DLT    CHANG1 2001             50               2             48
DLT.CAHNG2.2001        DLT    CAHNG2 2001             50               4             20
MSF.MARKETING.2001     MSF MARKETING 2001             20               2             16
MSF.CHANG1M.2001       MSF   CHANG1M 2001             50               6             20
MSF.CHANG2M.2001       MSF   CHANG2M 2001             36              10             20
```

Now you can filter and sort like this:

```
library(dplyr)
somefunc<-function(company.name,yearval){
    df2%>%filter(company==company.name,year==yearval)%>%arrange(-all_production)
}

>somefunc("DLT",2001)
  company  division year all_production good_production bad_production
1     DLT    CHANG1 2001             50               2             48
2     DLT    CAHNG2 2001             50               4             20
3     DLT Marketing 2001             30               4             20
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems OP has provided a very simple `sample data` which contains data for only year `2000`.

A solution approach could be:
1. Convert the list to data.frame
2. Use `gather` from `tidyr` to arrange dataframe in way where filter can be applied

```
    ll <- structure(list(company = c("DLT", "DLT", "DLT", "MSF", "MSF", "MSF"),
       division = c("Marketing", "CHANG1", "CAHNG2", "MARKETING", "CHANG1M",
 "CHANG2M"), all_production_2000 = c(15, 25, 25, 10, 25, 18),
       good_production_2000 = c(10, 24, 10, 8, 10, 10), 
       bad_production_2000 = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 5)))

df <- as.data.frame(ll)
library(tidyr)
gather(df, key = "key", value = "value", -c("company",  "division"))

#result:
# company  division                  key value
#1      DLT Marketing  all_production_2000    15
#2      DLT    CHANG1  all_production_2000    25
#3      DLT    CAHNG2  all_production_2000    25
#4      MSF MARKETING  all_production_2000    10
#5      MSF   CHANG1M  all_production_2000    25
#6      MSF   CHANG2M  all_production_2000    18
#7      DLT Marketing good_production_2000    10
#8      DLT    CHANG1 good_production_2000    24
#9      DLT    CAHNG2 good_production_2000    10
#10     MSF MARKETING good_production_2000     8
#11     MSF   CHANG1M good_production_2000    10
#12     MSF   CHANG2M good_production_2000    10
#13     DLT Marketing  bad_production_2000     2
#14     DLT    CHANG1  bad_production_2000     1
#15     DLT    CAHNG2  bad_production_2000     2
```

Now, filter can be applied easily on above data.frame.